# animating rotation of view IOS

Tags: ios, animation, rotation

Is there a way for me to animate my view controller rotating to fade out then fade in on the view rotation instead of the spinning motion?

have already tried dimming out then dimming in when rotation is detected, but as its dimming out you can see it starting to rotate

so probably need a way to disable the existing spin motion?

Comment: where are you adding the dimming animation, what function?

Comment: Im detecting the `UIViewContrller InterfaceOrientation` and dimming based on the value it produces but it doesn't mask the rotation animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting your dimmin animation in `UIViewController` method `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` or `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` or `willAnimateFirstHalfOfRotationToInterfaceOrientation`

Comment: yeah just sorted it using the `willAnimateFirstHalfOfRotationToInterfaceOrientation` and `willAnimateFirstSecondOfRotationToInterfaceOrientation` to cancel the existing animation. CHEERS